# React Redux not updating the props first time page is rendered

Tags: react-native, redux, react-redux

I've been having issues with react redux. Is it a trustful library?
Now, the first time I render my component, the props is not updated when the reducer is called.

My reducer:

```
import {
  GET_UNITS
} from '../actions/Types';

const INITIAL_STATE = {
  error: false,
  units: {},
};

export default (state = INITIAL_STATE, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case GET_UNITS:
      console.log('Reducer: '); console.log(action.payload);
      return { ...state, error: false, units: action.payload };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

My Action:

```
import {
  GET_UNITS
} from './Types';

export const getUnits = () => {
  return (dispatch) => {
    const units = {
        "1": "101",
        "2": "102",
        "3": "103",
        "4": "104",
    };
    dispatch({
      type: GET_UNITS,
      payload: units
    });
  };
};
```

This reducer name is util. I have more than one reducer, so I create a combineReducer

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
import AuthReducer from './Auth';
import Reduc1 from './Tenants';
import Reduce2 from './WorkOrders';
import Util from './Util';

export default combineReducers({
  auth: AuthReducer,
  reduc1: Reduc1,
  reduc2: Reduc2,
  util: Util
});
```

My app.js create the store

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import ReduxThunk from 'redux-thunk';
...
const store = createStore(reducers, {}, applyMiddleware(ReduxThunk));

    return (
      <Provider store={store}>
        <AppContainer
          ref={navigatorRef => {
            NavigationService.setTopLevelNavigator(navigatorRef);
          }}
        />
      </Provider>
    );
...
```

Below is the component where I try to use it:

```
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { getUnits } from '../../actions';
...
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      selectedUnit: undefined,
      units: {},
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.getUnitsAsync();
  }

  getUnitsAsync = async () => {
    await this.props.getUnits();
      console.log('Get Async'); console.log(this.props.units);
    this.setState({
      units: this.props.units
    });
  };
  ...
const mapStateToProps = ({ util }) => {
  const { error, units } = util;

  return { error, units };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, {
  getUnits
})(MyComponent);
```

When I run the application, I can see the logs:

```
Reducer: 
Object {
  "1": "101",
  "2": "102",
  "3": "103",
  "4": "104",
}
Get Async
Object {}
```

Why the log in my get async method is not updating the props? If I click on anything in the page that update the component, it works and update the this.props.units

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I *think*, though it's hard to say for sure, that your problem lies here:

```
await this.props.getUnits();
console.log('Get Async'); console.log(this.props.units);
this.setState({
  units: this.props.units
});
```

You are fetching your units and then as soon as they are returned, you write the current value of your props in to your state. I suspect that your props have not updated at this point, so you're storing an empty object.

Why are you using state to store your units instead of using them directly from your props? If you just use the props then your component will update and re-render when the updated props arrive from your store.

However, if you do need/want to respond to the updated props, you could write them to state in a lifecycle method like [`componentDidUpdate`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidupdate)

Comment: I thought we were supposed to use the state. If I use const { units } = this.props.units; I receive the error "Cannot convert undefined or null to object" because the first time the component is rendered the this.props.units is null

Comment: Your store *is* where (this part of) your state is. You don't/shouldn't need to store another copy of it.